# How much fuel could a rocket save by launching from an airship/blimp?

Tags: rockets, launch, fuel, balloons, skyhook

[image]
What could the [Kozlov’s Aerosmena project](https://t404t9.wixsite.com/aerosmena) blimp add to fuel saving if space rockets were launched from it? Where would you place the rocket and airship on this chart?

Comment: fuel usage per km is not a useful metric for space vehicles

Comment: Rockets can travel as far as you are willing to wait, and the optimal time to reach a destination is driven by orbital mechanics, independent of vehicle. This chart is basically useless for space travel, it only means something for vehicles that spend their time crawling around on a planetary surface or through its oceans/atmosphere.

Comment: To reiterate what has been said in many places. When you want to reach the orbit, gaining altitude is not the problem. The real problem is that you need to accelerate to the speed of 8 kilometers per second sideways. True, it is marginally easier to do that if you don't have to fight the extra drag of the thicker atmosphere the first few kilometers, but A) a rocket lifting off does not spend much time at low altitudes, B) its speed while there is "slow".

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen also, from what I could find, the maximum altitude of these blimps is only 3000 m. That's probably not when carrying their maximum payload. You're basically launching from a really expensive and weather-sensitive ground pad.

Comment: @OrganicMarble This graphic has nothing to do with space travel - what is called "Stage" here are just different stages of engine development.

Comment: @asdfex The last line in the question is "Where would you place the rocket and airship on this chart?"

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to point out a possible misunderstanding. Btw. The plot doesn't fit the data from tables on this "web page". The airship has to be about a factor 2 further to the left.

Answer (score 5):

If a rocket using cryogenic fuel and oxidizer is launched from a blimp, no fuel will be saved.

During the blimp flight from ground to launch height, the rocket will loose a lot of fuel by evaporation.

A rocket to reach an orbit at 400 km height and 8 km/s speed saves only very, very little fuel when launched from about 10 km height provided by a blimb.

So much more fuel is wasted by evaporation than saved by the increased launch height.